# How to compare Strings in BASH scripting?

Tags: string, bash, command-line, terminal

I just want to know how to read a String and then compare it. If it is "Plus", then carry on

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo -n Enter the First Number:
read num
echo -n Please type plus:
 read opr


if [ $num -eq 4 && "$opr"= plus ]; then

echo this is the right


fi
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash 

read -p 'Enter the First Number: ' num
read -p 'Please type plus: ' opr

if [[ $num -eq 4 && $opr == 'plus' ]]; then
    echo 'this is the right'
fi
```

If you're using bash then I strongly recommend using double brackets. They're a lot better than single brackets; for example, they handle unquoted variables a lot more sanely, and you can use `&&` inside the brackets.

If you use single brackets then you should write this:

```
if [ "$num" -eq 4 ] && [ "$opr" = 'plus' ]; then
    echo 'this is the right'
fi
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted opr to be compared against the string "plus" not the operator "+" ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo -n Enter the First Number:
read num
echo -n Please type plus:
 read opr


if [[ $num -eq 4 -a "$opr" == "plus" ]]; then
#               ^            ^    ^
# Implies logical AND        Use quotes for string
    echo this is the right
fi
```

Comment: It's `=`, not `==`, and extra quotes are not needed

Comment: Yep, I wanted to use the POSIX style i.e `==` with `[[ ... ]]`. Within a `[ ... ]`, I agree `=` is recommended. Using quotes avoids confusion and is a good practice especially when you have some special characters. For a string like plus it is optional.

Comment: Within `[]` the `=` is required, not merely recommended. And I agree quoting is good practice, but your comment gave the impression that the extra quotes would fix OP's problem. In general, I think it's best to add some explanation in an answer, instead of just dumping code.

Comment: Most modern bash shells allow using the `==` within the `[]` as well as `[[]]`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the question had the `bash` tag only. I was thinking of a "standard" shell.